# Encryption using java crypto library and RSA 4096 PublicKey not working properly

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am working with a third party and we have a requirement to encrypt email addresses before sending them over the network for privacy concerns. When I encrypt the email addresses using openssl on the command line everything works fine. However my Java 8 implementation generates encrypted strings which cannot be decrypted by the third party using their private key.

The private key is retrieved from the provider on-demand because they change their public keys at some interval. Here is an example of the response for a public key which is used to create the public key locally.

```
{"publicKey":"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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\nJN9kIq7QLV3ef+QUbzYiZZsCAwEAAQ==\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n","encryptionKeyId":"ENCRYPTION-KEY-ID-2020-04-01T18:00:13.367Z"}
```

Here is an example of encrypting strings using the command line that does work:

First receive the latest public key from the provider.

```
curl -s "http://stg.api.bazaarvoice.com/notifications/rsa_encryption_key/public/current/" | jq -r '.publicKey' > public_staging_key.pem

echo "testuser3@mailtest.nexus.bazaarvoice.com" | openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_staging_key.pem | xxd -p | tr -d '\n' > encrypted_example_1.txt
```

This encrypted email address can be properly decrypted by the third party with their private key.

Below is my java implementation which is generating email Addresses which cannot be decrypted by the third party using their private key.

```
@Bean
    @Qualifier(value="keySettings")
    public BazaarVoiceKeySettings keySettings() throws IOException {

        final String uri = bazaarVoiceSettings.getPiePublicKeyUri();

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        BazaarVoiceKeyResponse keyResponse = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, BazaarVoiceKeyResponse.class);
        BazaarVoiceKeySettings keySettings = new BazaarVoiceKeySettings();

        String pubKeyPEM = keyResponse.getPublicKey().replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "")
                .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replaceAll("\\s", "");

// create the key factory
        try {
            KeyFactory kFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            // decode base64 of your key
            byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(pubKeyPEM);
            // generate the public key
            X509EncodedKeySpec spec =  new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedBytes);
            RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) kFactory.generatePublic(spec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-512ANDMGF1PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaPublicKey);

            keySettings.setCipher(cipher);
            keySettings.setEncryptionKeyId(keyResponse.getEncryptionKeyId());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return keySettings;
    }
```

```
    private String encryptEmail(String emailAddress) throws BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
        Cipher cipher = keySettings.getCipher();
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(emailAddress.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        String encryptedString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(cipherText);

        return encryptedString;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't looked at your code or anything yet - but just for your information - the security employed by this third party provider is complete crap and they have no idea what they're doing.  They're sending you their public key over **unsecured** HTTP and then want you to jump through hoops to encrypt the email address when they could just use HTTPS and do away with all this crap...  And have it actually be secure too!

Comment: Your `openssl rsautl` is NOT using OAEP; by default for encryption it uses PKCS1v1.5 type 2 aka RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5, which `openssl` for hysterical raisins calls simply `-pkcs`. For similar raisins Java calls it **`RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding`** (case-insensitive). Also your `openssl` version is including a newline in the value encrypted, which may or may not matter to the server. @Luke: plus PCI doesn't care about email. Other things such as GDPR do, but not PCI.

Answer (score 1):

As @dave_thompson_085 answered, the solution was to change my encoding mode to **RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding**